# how to get the nth child of an element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

My code is below. It is created from a slider script.

```
<ul class="slick-dots" style="display: block;">
    <li aria-hidden="true">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
            <img style="pointer-events:none;" osrc="images/1234.jpg">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li aria-hidden="true">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
            <img style="pointer-events:none;" osrc="images/234.jpg">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li aria-hidden="true">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
            <img style="pointer-events:none;" src="images/456.jpg">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li aria-hidden="false" class="slick-active">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
            <img style="pointer-events:none;" src="images/7809.jpg">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to trigger any li based on another button click.

I tried the below codes for the same. But all of them triggers the last li of the set.

```
$("ul.slick-dots li").eq(1).trigger("click");
$($('ul.slick-dots').children()[2]).trigger("click");
$('.slick-dots > :nth-child(2)').trigger("click");
```

Is there any other solution for the problem or is it because of any mistake in my code.

Comment: basically it is all written here: https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: i think 1st and 3rd should work you can also write 3rd as `('.slick-dots li:nth-child(2)')`

Comment: Your code should work as expected just that we don't know what are you expecting?!

Comment: i added this code to fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/06bo6b7y/ . first and last one of the triggers working well. You should check something else. May be if you are using a plugin

Comment: I would like to trigger the third one or second one, but it always trigger the last one i.e the 4th element.

Comment: How do you check that it is the last element which been trigered? Obviously your observation is wrong. BUT again, we have no idea what it is supposed to do, nor how do you debug it. If you had provided a minimalistic sample replicating your issue, it would have been fixed long time ago

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#fire').click(function(){
fireClick(0);// for example u want to trigger the first li here
});
$('li').click(function(){
     $(this).css('border','1px solid black');
})
 function fireClick(element){
            var myTriggerPoint=element;
            $("ul.slick-dots li").each(function(i,ele){
                if(i==myTriggerPoint){
                    $(ele).trigger("click");
                }
             });
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slick-dots" style="display: block;">
    <li aria-hidden="true">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">list1
        </div>
    </li>
    <li aria-hidden="true">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">list2
        </div>
    </li>
    <li aria-hidden="true">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">list3
        </div>
    </li>
    <li aria-hidden="false" class="slick-active">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">list4
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id='fire'>fire click</div>
```

Comment: In your example, for `myTriggerPoint=1` it will target second `li`, not first one and anyway, this is useless to use each loop. OP posted code is better for sure

Comment: that also triggers last li element not the assigned one.

Comment: Looping over all matching elements just to test the index is a horrible way to do it, when there are many direct ways to access an element by index.

Answer (score 0):

I have here some examples how you can select your listItems `<li/>`
Or just simple click on any `<li>`

fyi: Just un-comment the relevant lines to see example working.

```js
// fake event
$(document).on('click', 'ul.slick-dots li', function() {
 $(this).css('background', 'red');
});


// trigger first child
//$('ul.slick-dots').children('li').get(0).click();
//$('ul.slick-dots').children('li:first-child').click();

// trigger second child
//$('ul.slick-dots').children('li').get(1).click();

// trigger last child
//$('ul.slick-dots').children('li').get(3).click();
//$('ul.slick-dots').children('li:last-child').click();

// trigger all
//$('ul.slick-dots').children('li').each(function() { $(this).click(); })
```

```css
ul {
  width: 50%;
}

li {
  height: 30px;
  background: grey;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slick-dots" style="display: block;">
    <li aria-hidden="true">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
            asdf
        </div>
    </li>
    <li aria-hidden="true">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
            asdf
        </div>
    </li>
    <li aria-hidden="true">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
            asdf
        </div>
    </li>
    <li aria-hidden="false" class="slick-active">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
            asdf
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or check out [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/ok6smj7d/)